# Show json in UI - indented with correct date time

Tags: c#-3.0, json.net

How can I show some text in json format in a properly indented way?

I am using Json.NET and I have serialized and saved my data with indenting, now I want to display this data inside my UI.

my text is coming out as:

{ "CompetencyId": 39, "Name": "Agriculture - Nurseries ", "DateAdded": "/Date(1337866574143+0100)/", "DateRemoved": "/Date(1337942762894+0100)/", "Status": "Active" }

*Note* I am simply reading from database and throwing it out

Question: Show json indented with the date in the correct format e.g. 18/06/2011

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RTFM: http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/

See:

- Serializing and Deserializing JSON / Serialization Settings / DateFormatHandling
- Reading and Writing JSON / JsonTextWriter